# matcher.find() matches too much

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I am confused by my Matcher's find() method returning more matches than I thought my regex would create.  Below is the JUnit test I wrote to try to hash this out.  All the tests pass, but I don't understand why my find() return matches whose group( 1 ) value is null or empty (see // Why more find()s than actual matches? commend in the code)?

```
public class JustTheDigits {
    @Test
    public void testJustTheDigits() {
        doTest( "DV_APLCN: 563 ,DV_DHR_APLCN: 5632, PIC_NOTE: 6254", new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList( 563, 5632, 6254 ) ) );
        doTest( "563 ,DV_DHR_APLCN: 5632, PIC_NOTE", new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList( 563, 5632 ) ) );
        doTest( "hello 563 jello", new ArrayList<Integer>( Arrays.asList( 563 ) ) );
        doTest( "Hello World", new ArrayList<Integer>() );
    }

    private void doTest( String candidate, List<Integer> expected ) {
        List<Integer> actual = justTheDigits( candidate );
        assertEquals( expected, actual );
    }

    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+)?" );

    public List<Integer> justTheDigits( String input ) {
        List<Integer> listOfDigits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input );
        while ( matcher.find() ) {
            String s = matcher.group( 1 );
            // Why more find()s than actual matches?
            if ( s != null && "".equals( s ) == false ) {
                listOfDigits.add( Integer.parseInt( s ) );
            }
        }
        return listOfDigits;
    }
}
```

What, if anything, can I do to my regex to avoid the bloody not null or empty check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `?` so that your regex is simply `(\\d+)` as your regex is matching when there is a series of one or more digits, one or more times.  Even if there are no digits, the regex will still match.

Comment: Aw, geez.  It is that easy.  I love RegEx.  I struggle with RegEx.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ? question mark says the previous statement is optional. In literal terms you are asking for 0 or 1 of at least 1 of any digit.

Change the pattern to `"\\d+"` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

i believe you are saying you want a group of any one or more digits to show up once *or not at all*. that is why if it doesn't find it it will still return a match. i'm not sure exactly what you want to do, but i think you'd probably be fine with "\d+"